# General Guidance on Integration of Sidewalks With Roads

Tags: network-analyst, network

I am trying to prepare a network dataset for network analysis. I have a road network that is pretty well constructed, and a pedestrian network that is not as well constructed.[image: Red is Sidewalks and Pedestrian Paths, Blue is Roads]

The red Lines represent sidewalks and pedestrian paths, the blue lines represent roads.

Is there a way I can quickly and efficiently integrate the two to proper network connectivity standards? or will I have to go through by hand and connect everything manually? the sidewalks are often disconnected from each other where they intersect with roads, and the crosswalks are not modeled.

If there is no way to integrate them without a great deal of effort, would it be simpler just to indicate the presence of sidewalks as an attribute in the roads, and just connect the standalone paths? connecting every sidewalk and every crosswalk would be an enormous undertaking.

[image]

Comment: In the second picture, it seems you need the pedestrian walkway under the railroad. If you integrate sidewalks as an attribute of roads, you would lose that connection, and any routing would take a long way around.

Comment: On the other hand, maybe you remove the sidewalk lines that run parallel to roads, integrate them as road attributes, and retain only the walkways that go where the roads do not.

Comment: There's a few implications to the attribute approach. The first being that i need to implement a bunch of barriers in places where roads intersect but there is not a crosswalk in each direction. the second is that my travel time calculations will be incorrect. But it would also take a LOT less work

Comment: People will usually cross the road without a crosswalk, except on very busy streets. So you could implement your "barrier" solution only on major roads, and assume that people will cross side streets at any intersection.

Comment: Thanks ! this is what we actually ended up doing. it had the side effect of counteracting some counterintuitive pathing behavior as well. we ended up only using sidewalks on streets classified as major collector or higher, and just had the pathing occur on the streets for less busy streets. we still neeeded to connect a lot of things by hand, but the end result is working well.